# Getting incorrect answer while solving $P\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leq \frac{y^2}{x^2} \leq \sqrt{2}\right)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given below is the question I am solving. I believe I am doing everything correct but the answer is wrong at the end and I can't figure out why. Please help me. I will appreciate it.

The correct answer written in the book is $0.1591.$

**Problem**

find $P\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leq \frac{y^2}{x^2} \leq \sqrt{2}\right)$
where joint pdf of $x, y$ is:
$$
f_{x, y}(x, y)=1, \begin{aligned}
& 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
& 0 \leq y \leq 1
\end{aligned}
$$

**Solution**
Solving the inequality $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leq \frac{y^2}{x^2} \leq \sqrt{2}$
gives us
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2}} \leq y^2 \leq \sqrt{2} x^2 \\
\Rightarrow & \frac{x}{2^{\frac{1}{4}}} \leq y \leq 2^{\frac{1}{4}} x\\\Rightarrow&2^{-\frac{1}{4}} x \leq y \leq 2^{\frac{1}{4}}x
\end{aligned}
$$
hence the problem becomes
\begin{aligned}
P\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leq \frac{y^2}{x^2} \leq \sqrt{2}\right)&=P\left(2^{\frac{-1}{4}}x \leq y \leq 2^{\frac{1}{4}}x\right) \\
&=\int_0^1 \int_{2^\frac{-1}{4} x}^{2^\frac{1}{4} x} f(x, y) d x d y \\
&=\int_0^1 \int_{2^{-\frac{1}{4} }x}^{2^{\frac{1}{4}}x} 1 \cdot d x \cdot d y \\
& =\left.\int_0^1(y)\right|_{2^\frac{-1}{4} x} ^{2^{\frac{1}{4}} x} d x \\
& =\int_0^1\left(2^{\frac{1}{4}} x-{2^\frac{-1}{4}} x\right) d x \\
& =\left.\left(2^{\frac{1}{4}} \frac{x^2}{2}\right)\right|_0 ^1-\left.\left(2^{-\frac{1}{4}} \frac{x^2}{2}\right)\right|_0 ^1 \\
& =\left(2^{\frac{1}{4}} \cdot \frac{1^2}{2}\right)-\left(2^{\frac{-1}{4}} \cdot \frac{1^2}{2}\right) \\
& =\left(2^{\frac{1}{4}} \cdot 2^{-1}\right)-\left(2^{-\frac{1}{4}} \cdot 2^{-1}\right) \\
& =2^\frac{-3}{4}-2^{-\frac{5}{4}}\\
& =0.5946-0.4204 \\
& =0.1741
\end{aligned}

Comment: Very hard to read since there are many typos.

Comment: I have corrected them now

Comment: There are still typos at many places

Comment: Anyways, note that $2^{1/4}>1$ And your density is zero outside of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ so you must be more careful in the limits of integration, particularly what $x$ you should integrate over

Comment: I didn't get your point sir. How does it help in my question?

Comment: I have fixed all typos. Read it few times carefully. couldnt spot any anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your density:
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1, & 0\leq x, y \leq 1\\
0, & \text{else}\end{cases}$$

tells you that you can only substitute $f(x,y)$ with $1$ as long as you integrate over the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. What this means is that
$$P(2^{\frac{-1}{4}}x\leq y \leq 2^{\frac{1}{4}}x)$$
depends on $x$ because whenever $y>1$ or $y<0$ your density would give you zero.

In particular when $0\leq x\leq 1$ we have
$$0\leq2^{\frac{-1}{4}}x \leq 2^{\frac{-1}{4}} <1$$
so no problems here. However, when $0 \leq x \leq 1$ we have
$$0\leq 2^{\frac{1}{4}}x \leq 2^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
where the middle expression takes on each value at some $x$, and so we can see that there exists $x$ when $2^{\frac{1}{4}}x > 1$. For such $x$ you have to substitute the upper limit by $1$. That is to say
$$P(2^{\frac{-1}{4}}x \leq y \leq 2^{\frac{1}{4}}x) = P(2^{\frac{-1}{4}}x \leq y \leq \min(1, 2^{\frac{1}{4}}x))$$

Thus you would get

$$P\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leq \frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}\leq\sqrt{2}\right) = \int_{0}^{2^{\frac{-1}{4}}}\int_{2^{\frac{-1}{4}}x}^{2^{\frac{1}{4}}x}1 \ dydx + \int_{2^{\frac{-1}{4}}}^{1}\int_{2^{\frac{-1}{4}}x}^{1}1 \ dydx = 0.1591\dots$$